# Translating by adding coordinate constants in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, translation

Can you add coordinate constants to ArcGIS shapefiles?

I can do this in QGIS with the Translate tool but can't find a similar tool in ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.

Comment: If geometry is point, can be done with 1 line in field calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in an edit session. (right click on your layer, then "start editing")

```
Select the entities that you want to move

go to the Editor menu in the Editor toolbar

select "move" 

enter the shift values for X and Y translation (also Z if you have 3D analyst)
```